# Getting error BAD.REQUEST 400 when trying fetching [GET] data from a specific route of freelancer API?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, bad-request

I'm working with freelancer API, I want to fetch user data from this endpoint **/users/0.1/users/**
but I keep getting error:

> error_code: "RestExceptionCodes.BAD_REQUEST"
> message: "Please provide users[] or usernames[] query"

freelancer-api: [List Users](https://developers.freelancer.com/docs/users/users#users-get)

```
function fetchV2(urlOb, headerOb, paramsOb) {
  Object.keys(paramsOb).forEach(key => urlOb.searchParams.append(key, paramsOb[key]))
  return fetch(urlOb, headerOb)
}
```

```
let header = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
       'freelancer-oauth-v1': *********
      }
  }
let url = new URL(`https://www.freelancer.com/api/users/0.1/users/`);
let params = {users:[123456,654321]};
let res = await fetchV2(url, header, params);
let data = await res.json();
console.log(data);
```

I also tried to query with one `user_id` and but again I get the same error.

I successfully working with other routes (using the same structures) but I don't know what am I missing here!
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To others that may help them, I found out there is no standard method to pass array parameters to URLs, which means that the URLSearchParams API doesn't support parsing arrays or objects.
so I built a function to make it manually:

```
function test() {

  let url = 'https://www.freelancer.com/api/users/0.1/users/'

  let paramsArray = {
    users: [11111111, 22222222, 33333333],
    username:['p1','p2','p3']
  }

  let arrString = ''
  for (const property in paramsArray) {
    arrString += paramsArray[property].map(item => {
      return `${property}[]=${item}&`
    }).join('')
  }


  let paramsNotArray = {
    display_info: true,
    status: true,
  }
  const params = new URLSearchParams(paramsNotArray)

  url = `${url}?${arrString}${params.toString()}`

  return fetch(url)
}
```

here is the [article](https://medium.com/raml-api/arrays-in-query-params-33189628fa68).